# Two+ Monitors with 2 video cards in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, pci

In windows xp I use to be able to have three monitors, two running off my PCIe and 1 running of a PCI card.  Since then I have upgraded to windows 7 and can only get one card to be enabled (one or the other, but they both do work). Is there any way to be able to get a tripple monitor setup without buying new stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some vendors don't want the expense of making a new driver to allow their lower-end PCI cards to work with 7. I ran into the same problem and had to buy a new PCI card that explicitly stated that it worked on Windows 7. 3x monitors is possible though.

Comment: I know it's possible but the only way I have seen it was with SLI. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The driver model was changed in Windows 7 from Vista, allowing heterogenous GPU's to coexist peacefully.  My current Windows 7 box has 1 Nvidia card and 1 ATI card, running a total of 3 monitors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model:
  "Support multiple drivers in a multi-adapter, multi-monitor setup"

What are the two cards?

Comment: An Ati 9200SE(PCI) and Ati 5xxx HD series (Don't remember off the top of my head and I'm not at my desktop right now).